# Manipulating and Outputting JSON in Ruby

Tags: json, ruby

I have a JSON return (is it a hash? array? JS object?) where every entry is information on a person and follows the following format:

```
{"type"=>"PersonSummary", 
"id"=>"123", "properties"=>{"permalink"=>"personname", 
"api_path"=>"people/personname"}}
```

I would like to go through every entry, and output only the "id"

I've put the entire JSON pull "response" into "result"

```
result = JSON.parse(response)
```

then, I'd like to go through result and do print the ID and "api_path" of the person:

> result.each do |print id AND api_path|

How do I go about doing this in Ruby?

Answer (score 2):

The only time you would need to use `JSON.parse` is if you have a string you need to parse into a `Hash`. For Example:

```
result = JSON.parse('{ "type" : "PersonSummary", "id" : 123, "properties" : { "permalink" : "personname", "api_path" : "people/personname" } }')
```

Once you have the `Hash`, `result` could be accessed by giving it the `key`, like `result[:id]` or `result['id']` (both will work), or you can iterate through the hash too using the following code.

If you need to access the `api_path` value you would do so by using `result['properties']['api_path']`

```
result = { 'type' => 'PersonSummary', 'id' => 123, 'properties' => { 'permalink' => 'personname', 'api_path' => 'people/personname' } }

result.each do |key, value|
  puts "Key: #{key}\t\tValue: #{value}"
end
```

You could even do something like `puts value if key == 'id'` if you just want to show certain values.